# What is the difference between asio::tcp::socket's async_read_some and async_receive?

Tags: c++, boost-asio

What is the difference between:

- `boost::asio::tcp::socket::async_read_some()`
- `boost::asio::tcp::socket::async_receive()`

As far as I can tell their documentation is identical.

Which should I prefer?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Their specification in the [networking TR2 proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n2054.pdf) (5.7.10.2 basic_stream_socket members) is identical too:

On async_receive:

> Effects: Calls this->service.async_receive(this->implementation, buffers, 0, handler).

On async_read_some:

> Effects: Calls this->service.async_receive(this->implementation, buffers, 0, handler).

So I guess this confirms Jerry's impression.

Comment: Jerry's answer is better. Gives some reason `why` this may be so.

Answer (score 25):

I believe the two are essentially identical. The reason they provide both is to provide interfaces similar to both iostreams (which have a `read_some` member) and sockets (which have a `receive`).

As Peter Tseng pointed out, `async_receive` does also have an overload that accepts `socket_base::message_flags`, which `async_read_some` does not.

Comment: Makes sense to me. So I guess he should "prefer" the one matching the interface he'd rather keep compatability with.

Comment: async_receive accepting socket_base::message_flags is worth mentioning

Comment: @PeterTseng: Mentioning that is why I just up-voted (apparently, your edit to) Adrien Clerc's answer... :-)

Answer (score 3):

Confirming everyone here with two links:

1. https://github.com/boostorg/asio/blob/36eef63a9cf8ae609716d76ccb3906ff9769d53a/include/boost/asio/basic_stream_socket.hpp#L558
2. https://github.com/boostorg/asio/blob/36eef63a9cf8ae609716d76ccb3906ff9769d53a/include/boost/asio/basic_stream_socket.hpp#L834

The code is exactly the same. However `async_receive` has one overload with message_flags, which notably allows you to specify `asio::socket_base::message_peek`.